# How to properly make timer in turn-based application using Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, timer

I am currently working on multiplayer memory game with C#, Windows Forms and I got stuck making a timer.

Player 1 receives a token so he can discover two squares (in this time other players are waiting), then passes the token to next player. Each client runs in a separate thread. For communication with server I used Newtonsoft JSON network for .NET. I made the timer using System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Client receiving token, starting the timer.

```cs
    case "Token":
        Message tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(unknown.obj.ToString());
        Token = tok.number;
        timeLeft.Text = "10";
        TimeRemaining.Start();
        allowClick = true;
        break;
```

Function that counts down the time, shows how much seconds left and after time passed sends token back.

```cs
private void TimerRemaining_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int timer = Convert.ToInt32(timeLeft.Text);
    timer -= 1;
    timeLeft.Text = Convert.ToString(timer);
    if (timer ==0)
    {
        TimeRemaining.Stop();
        allowClick=false;
        MessageBox.Show("End of time");
        SendBack(Token);
    }
}
```

The timer works fine but only for the first round. After receiving token for the second time, the timer does not start again.

Have you got any suggestions, or solutions that could help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try resetting `timeLeft.Text` to the time given in a round before `TimeRemaining.Start()`.

Comment: I tried, label has changed back to 10 but countdown doesnt start and label value remains unchanged.